# security in sql server 2008 r2, create special user

Tags: sql, database

I have a system win server 2008/ sql server 2008 r2 where
sql server is accessed by remote user (the same but multiple connections).

I need to have a user who can create/alert databases but I do not want to put him
in sysadmin.

When I add user to public  and dbowner role that is enough to run query and create databases
but he can not alter database. Granting user explicit permission to alter has no effect.
The only time it works is when I put user in  sysadmin role.

When user creates database from remote location (c# exe) I need to alter several options 
because I do not need transaction logs for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following articles: [server-level roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx) and [database-level roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx), they are good primers on standard MSSQL security.

The dbcreator role should let a user define a new database and its required files, if that's not sufficient, then you should look into the diskadmin role.

Comment: by some reason does not work in my case, gave user all db level roles on master/model (except deny) also dbcreator and diskadmin. I am thinking this might be some unique weird case. Thank you for reply.